# Curved line that connects treble staff and bass staff

Tags: theory, piano, sheet-music

I'm new to piano and have stumbled across a bent line that connects notes on the treble staff and bass staff. What does it mean?[image]

Comment: This has to be a dupe!

Answer (score 4):

It's phrasing mark, and it connect the notes of a musical phrase. In this case it's also showing that the final C in the left hand belongs to the right hand melody.

Comment: I feel like that C should have a stem going up as well.

Comment: If this was a piece for two different instruments, violin and cello perhaps, yes.   For piano, no.   Piano music continually changes the number of 'voices'.  No need to notate as if it doesn't.